# My python string variable in my if statements are not working

Tags: python

I think its something to do with my if statements but i cant figure out what.

Im trying to have the user enter 1 of 3 options, and if they type something else, it will restart them. Every time i type something that's not one of the choices, it prints restart as normal. But if i type one of the choices it always comes up with "It has o". I've tried switching the elif and if around. I may not have tried everything though.

```
import math
 
choices = ["o","a","h"]

#ang = float(input("Angle: "))
unk = str(input("Unknown side (o,a,h): "))

if unk.lower() in choices:
    print("It has o")
elif unk.lower() in choices:
    print("It has a")
elif unk.lower() in choices:
    print("It has h")        
else:
    print("restart")
```

Comment: All your `if/elif` conditions are the same, so if the first is true, python will pick the first and ignore the others.

Answer (score 2):

Read the code aloud - If your input is a valid choice, print it, else print "restart".

There's only two conditions there, not four.

```
unk = input("Unknown side (o,a,h): ")

if unk.lower() in choices:
    print(f"It has {unk.lower()}")
else:
    print("restart")
```